# Place embed place how to bring back in editable mode

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

File > place embedded →
This is how we import the files.
see attachment →
[image]

But as soon as we right click and then click place:
[image]

Then how can we bring back in editable mode? where we can change size etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Please consider reviewing some basic tutorials: 
[Get to know Photoshop from Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/how-to/ps-basics-fundamentals.html)

This is really core knowledge regarding the application functionality. Reviewing basic tutorials will assist you in working more quickly rather than having to post questions about basic functionality.

To resize content on a layer...

Highlight the layer in the **Layers Panel** then choose 
`Edit > Free Transform` or `Edit  > Transform > [whatever option you want]`

Comment: It is not just about resizing, but I want the layer to be coming up in the editable mode again as shown in the first image.